# limits of two equivalent sequences

Tags: real-analysis

How does one prove, that if $x_n$ and $y_n$ are two equivalent sequences, such that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{y_n}=1$$
Then convergence of $x_n$ implies convergence of $y_n$?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}{y_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\frac{y_n}{x_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{y_n}{x_n}=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\right)1
=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n.
$$
All the steps are correct? Why?

Comment: You can't do that when $x_n$ has 0 for its limit no?

Comment: You can't do that when some of the $x_n$ are $0$.

Comment: That's why I prefer to say: $x_n$ equivalent to $y_n$ <=> $x_n$ -$y_n$ = o($y_n$)

Comment: The problem isn't $\lim x_n=0$, but $x_n=0$ for a infinite number of $n$'s. Can happen?

Comment: Agreed, hence the alternative to the ratio

Comment: @Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla: $x_n=2^{-n}+(-2)^{-n}$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, with $x_=2^{-n}+(-2)^{-n}$ is possible $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{y_n}=1$?

Comment: @Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla: indeed, no.

Answer (score 0):

let L be the limit of $x_n$ . If L $\neq$ 0 :

Then if $y_n$ doesn't converge, the ratio doesn't converges towards 1, so there is an absurdity.

If L=0, you write: $x_n$ equivalent to $y_n$ <=> $y_n$ -$x_n$ = o($x_n$)

So $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n$ = 0